How do I fix my kitchen sink popup drain stopper?
My kitchen sink has one of those little shelves in the drain that pop up and down
One day I went to pull it up and the whole think came apart.

This looks like it should be simple, but the thing is the pin in the middle is not threaded it is smooth all the way around - So how did it remain attached to the metal shelf in the past? I used to be able to pull the whole thing off and it would remain all together.
Is there a way to repair this?

Looks like a part broke off and went down the drain.  You need to get a new one.

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of this "popper."  Unless the rubber part acts as a stopper in some kind of hole in the drain?

The cost of labour and any materials needed, will probably be greater than the cost of a new one.  I like to repair stuff also, but like to know when to hold them and when to toss them.

You may have lost a push nut from the bottom of the pin. A common sign would be scratches on the skinny end of the pin from the sharp edges on the nut. The part might be lurking in the drain trap.

A pic of the sink drain could help here.

You can buy a replacement for the whole thing.

You could replace the push-on washer lost down the drain (similar to those shown in this assortment from Amazon) with one from a local hardware store. You might peen the small end of the stud after applying the washer to avoid it's loss.
Alternatively, use a stainless steel bolt and two stainless steel nuts to replace metal stud: one nut above the rubber washer and metal disk, one nut below. Use a  locking (Nylock) nut at bottom, or a stainless steel lockwasher or apply thread-locking compound to avoid the issue recurring.
